# Make My Entity Framework Code more Efficient

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

We have a `Repository` class. While this class has some custom behavior, it wraps a standard `ObjectContext` object and so it's primarily standard Entity Framework.

Currently, we have the following code block, which works but performs horribly. (`target` is a `CostingLineItem`. The code changes the `AddedByEmployee` reference for this `CostingLineItem`.)

```
if (target.AddedByEmployee != null)
    target.AddedByEmployee.CostingLineItems.Remove(target);
byEmployee.CostingLineItems.Add(target);
target.AddedByEmployee = byEmployee;
```

Because we have lazy loading enabled, this bit of code loads both the `target.AddedByEmployee.CostingLineItems` and `byEmployee.CostingLineItems` collections, which could be many thousands of rows.

Unfortunately, I can't change the lazy loading setting for this code. I need to find a way to make it more efficient, but nothing seems to work for me.

Here's what I've tried so far.

---

**Method 1:**

```
target.AddedByEmployeeId = byEmployee.Id;
```

Has no effect. The `AddedByEmployeeId` column still contains the original value. Apparently, the original employee reference is still there and takes priority.

---

**Method 2:**

```
target.AddedByEmployee = byEmployee;
```

Throws the following exception. Again, seems the original employee reference is still there.

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Employees' of the relationship 'Leo.Domain.FK_CostingLineItem_Employees' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

---

**Method 3:**

```
Repository.Detach(target.AddedByEmployee);
target.AddedByEmployee = byEmployee;
```

`Detach()` (which in turn calls `ObjectContext.Detach()`) throws the following exception:

> The object cannot be detached because it is not attached to the ObjectStateManager.

---

**Method 4:**

```
target.AddedByEmployee.CostingLineItems.Remove(target);
target.AddedByEmployee = byEmployee;
```

This works! But it's still loading `target.AddedByEmployee.CostingLineItems`, which I would like to avoid.

---

I realize I have not shown all of our code here (that's just not possible). But the code is using a standard `ObjectContext` underneath. What I would really like is someone who has some insights into Entity Framework and can offer some ideas for what else I can try, or what else I can check.

*Note: We are currently running Visual Studio 2012. I will see if we can update to 2015. I would love to know if anything has changes since the version we are using that could make some of the methods above work where they didn't before.*

Comment: Lazy loading is a killer, first prize would be to turn it off, but as you mention you can't.  Could you just execute raw `SQL` using the context?

Comment: Is the lazy loading a blocking call?  If the related collections are being loaded asynchronously, it might not matter.

Comment: @3dd: I think for our next project, we might just always have lazy loading disabled. Unfortunately, this is part of some very complex code that is written by other code to follow certain rules defined in an XML file. So writing raw SQL isn't a good solution for this.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It is blocking, and it visibly slow. That's certainly an interesting suggestion, but this action is initiated by a drag and drop operation. I don't believe we could update the page content until the operation has completed in full.

Comment: Can you post the relevant entity configuration (Data Annotations or Fluent API)?

Comment: With Method 1, have you tried setting `target.AddedByEmployee = null` in addition to setting the Id?

Comment: @Vlad274: Not sure what you are asking for. This is not code first. Yes, I've also tried setting it to null first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some extensive research and testing, I think I determined what my issues were.

The problem was that the entity in question had just been cloned in the database. The cloning code follows a bunch of rules that dictate if related items are also cloned or only the references are cloned.

Either way, the `AddedByEmployee` had already been set. And so trying to set it a second time, or simply trying to set the ID has problems because of the conflict with what was already set.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the target directly from the `DbSet<>` rather that removing it from the attached `CostingLineItems`.

```
context.Set<CostingLineItems>().Remove(target)
```

This should remove the target without loading the collection.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try it but I looked at that. The problem is that, unlike `Remove`ing an item from a collection, this syntax will mark the item for deletion. I don't want to actually delete the item.

Comment: if the key is nullable, it should be possible to set the employee id on target to null, and save it to remove the link. You mention you have tried that though

Comment: It is nullable, but yeah setting the ID to null, 0 or anything else doesn't save to the database. There is apparently still that reference to the old item, which seems to be taking priority.

Comment: You have to call `SaveChanges` after calling `Remove`

Comment: @Bauss: Yes, none of this code would do anything if `SaveChanges()` didn't get called.

Comment: @JonathanWood if you set the ID to null, EF should delete the relationship. How do you do change tracking? Do you need to manually set ObjectState = TrackingState.Modified?

Comment: @Vlad274: I do not understand why I'd need something like that. This type of thing has always been automatic. Do you have a link to some resources that describe situations where I need that?

Comment: @JonathanWood EF determines what call to make to the DB by looking at the ObjectContext and determining the ObjectState of those objects. This can be done automatically or explicitly, if you're not familiar with it, it's likely something in your solution is doing it automatically. I'd advise you to avoid diving into this as it's probably a Red Herring, but a good resource: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx